# How to predict data after saving the machine learning model

Tags: python, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

I am building a recommendation system using cosine similarity. I have already trained my model but now I'm not sure how to make prediction after saving the model.

```
captions = data["Caption"].tolist()

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
uni_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(captions)


uni_sim =  cosine_similarity(uni_tfidf[0:1], uni_tfidf).flatten()



similarity = uni_sim.argsort()[:-5:-1]
for sim in similarity:
    print(captions[sim])
```

this is what I have implemented using posts caption, but this model is predicting values based on the data in the dataset. I want to know after I save this model will it take the input and how will it take it and which line will help me predict the model [I'm new to Machine Learning so its difficult to understand even some basic concept]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can export the object with Pickle or Joblib then call `transform` from it on your new data.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. I'll try it